# Rails could not find a temporary directory (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I'm uploading my Rails proyect to a Ubuntu Server running 12.04LTS and I can't seem to fix this issue! Whether I do a bundle install or try to use the whenever gem I get that error! I've read a lot but still I'm unable to fix it

```
/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:34:in `tmpdir': could not find a temporary directory (ArgumentError)
```

And my ls -la of the / folder
[image: Error]

Any ideas?
P.s I tried chmod -R 777 on /tmp with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: As suggested in the comments just run

```
chmod +t /tmp
```

========

Old answer:

Your Ubuntu installation probably doesn't have `TMPDIR` set. You should set that variable in your startup.

This link has more information on environment variables in Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: It is not enough to set TMPDIR to _any_ directory path. The directory must be readable, writeable and either _not_ be writeable or have a sticky bit. Besides, there are alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31182540/601203.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is to just run this like @hagello suggests.

```
chmod +t /tmp
```

Then it should start working again.