# Rails uploading file with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I want to upload a file with paperclip to amazon AWS S3.

Running a Rails 4.2 app on debian

But I got this error:

```
ERROR ArgumentError: could not find a temporary directory
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Create a tmp folder in your app?

Comment: have one already... thats no the problem I think

Comment: Is there a /tmp directory in the filesystem? Does your webserver have permission to write to it?

Comment: yes in the root of the projectfolder. I set chmode 0777 to it ..., should I set for a subfolder two?

Comment: Possible dupplicate: [stackoverflow.com/questions/21117878](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117878/ruby-could-not-find-a-temporary-directory)